# Proxy Authentication Error in pip install Mac

Tags: terminal, mac, bash, proxy

I have tried to set the proxy in the bash_profile:

export http_proxy=http://UserID:PWD@202.141.80.24:3128

export https_proxy=http://UserID:PWD@202.141.80.24:3128

export ftp_proxy=http://UserID:PWD@202.141.80.24:3128

Also since my password contains an '@' symbol I escaped it with \ and also tried to replace it with %40.

And I am saving the changes and updating the profile using source ~/.bash_profile

Despite all this, when I run the command:

sudo pip install kmeans-smote

I get Proxy Authentication Error:

[image: Error]

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Variables in bash are case sensitive and most software expects the proxy to be set in uppercase. It's also a good idea to quote strings as you never know what can upset bash.

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://UserID:PWD@202.141.80.24:3128"

export HTTPS_PROXY="http://UserID:PWD@202.141.80.24:3128"

export FTP_PROXY="http://UserID:PWD@202.141.80.24:3128"
```

*NOTE* For these sort of shell questions [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is usually better for a quick answer.

Comment: This isn't working either.